# MDX / Cubemember / Excel

Tags: excel, mdx

Hopefully someone can help, I'm fairly new to MDX and am trying to create an excel template that will be updated automatically.

I have a basic cube setup and I have created a pivot table and have changed the pivot to show the formulas, I have then updated the formulas from A1 etc to the member name so that they can be moved into a different tab in excel.

[image: The below shows my excel values]

```
A2 =CUBEMEMBER("cubeconnection","[Data Date].[Working Day In Quarter].&[64]")

B2 =CUBEMEMBER("cubeconnection",{"[Data Date].[Working Day In Quarter].&[64]","[Data Date].[Data Date].&[2018-12-31T00:00:00]"})

C2 =CUBEVALUE("cubeconnection","[Data Date].[Quarter Offset].&[1]","[Data Date].[Working Day In Quarter].&[64]","[Measures].[Closing Base]")
```

I want to be able to setup `B2` to be dynamic and not include the reference `"[Data Date].[Data Date].&[2018-12-31T00:00:00]"` but still display the date as when the next quarter report runs the date won't be `2018-12-31` but a new date.

Is there a way to reference my workingdayinquarter field and bring back the member of datadate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try `EXISTS` with a reference to cell `A2` rather than hard-coding it into `B2`.

`EXISTS` example from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/exists-mdx?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,  
EXISTS(  
[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS  
, {[Customer].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US]}  
) ON 1   
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Cool reference to help with CUBE FUNCTIONS: https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/12/cube-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-how-to-make-them-great/

So for B2 maybe try this:

```
=CUBEMEMBER("cubeconnection","EXISTS( [Data Date].[Data Date].MEMBERS, {" & A2 & "}).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sample below. It uses vba functions to get the last date of any quater

```
select 

tail({
(
strtomember('[Dim Date].[Year].&['+cstr(datepart("yyyy",Now()))+ ']')
,
strtomember('[Dim Date].[Quarter].&['+cstr(datepart("q",Now()))+ ']')
,[Dim Date].[Date].[Date]
)
}
,1)
on columns
from cube
```

Result

[image]

You wound need to modify the portion within the tail function, and put that in your excel cell

Comment: @JoelG does the above help?

Comment: I had to do it in MDX so unfortunately not, but the above answer has solved my issue. Thanks for your time/help

Comment: You are most welcome. Just for info VBA functions are natural in MDX, so the above code is MDX